# how do I add style to my label in google maps with the google maps api?

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps

I've made a map calling multiple data points from my json file I've managed to display an image as a marker and get a label to display but my issue is with the label how do I add style to it without it breaking my map or messing with the coordinates?

Currently, the first label works and is in the right place but the second way I'm trying to initialise it doesn't even work and as far as my research has shown that how it has to be laid out to add style.

- tried adding style to the initial label stopped the whole map from displaying.
- tried adding a label in the formative seen can't even get the text to display

```
  //stores Google Map object and the JSON called from PHP
  var map;
  var locations;
  var markers;


  function initMap() {

      // creates the map and puts it in the html giving its zoom and position
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
          {
            center: {
                lat: 51.0590282, 
                lng: -1.3104568},
                zoom: 9
        });


    $.getJSON(

          //URL for my php script
          'http://up858296.ct.port.ac.uk/ParkRun/ParkrunJson.php', 

          function(jsonData) {   

              // putting jason data under variable location
              locations  = jsonData;

              locations.forEach(
```

```
                        function(loc) {


                            // gets objects which arent in my JSON
                            loc.map = map;  

                            if (loc.gender == "Male") {

                                loc.icon.url = 'Man.png';

                            } else {

                                loc.icon.url = 'Women.png';
                            }

                            loc.icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(40, 40);
                            loc.icon.labelOrigin = new google.maps.Point(10, 50);
                            loc.title = "Parkrun: " + loc.parkrun + ", Runner: " + loc.name + ", Time: " + loc.duration;
                            //fist label that displays but cant add style

                            loc.label =  loc.name + ", Time:" + loc.duration;                                                                               


                            //creates marker on google map named "loc"
                            // "loc" stores lat, lng ect 
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(loc);

                            // Add listener for a click event upon which will open url for parkrun sites.
                            marker.addListener(

                                'click',

                                function() {
                                    window.open(loc.link);
                                }

                            );

                        //initialise styled map label overlay (second lable wont even display text)
                        /*var m = new google.maps.Marker({
                                           position: loc,
                                           label: {
                                            text: loc.name + ", Time:" + loc.duration,
                                            color: 'white',
                                            fontWeight: 'bold',

                                          },
                                        })*/                    
                        }
                  );
             }
        );

      };
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (using the formatting from your second attempt for the label defined in the first).

```
  loc.icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(40, 40);
  loc.icon.labelOrigin = new google.maps.Point(10, 50);
  loc.title = "Parkrun: " + loc.parkrun + ", Runner: " + loc.name + ", Time: " + loc.duration;
  loc.label = {
    text: loc.name + ", Time:" + loc.duration,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  };
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/16mufxg5/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var locations;
var markers;


function initMap() {
  // creates the map and puts it in the html giving its zoom and position
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 51.0590282,
      lng: -1.3104568
    },
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });

  // putting jason data under variable location
  locations = jsonData;

  locations.forEach(
    function(loc) {
      // gets objects which arent in my JSON
      loc.map = map;
      if (loc.gender == "Male") {
        loc.icon.url = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png';
      } else {
        loc.icon.url = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png';
      }
      loc.icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(40, 40);
      loc.icon.labelOrigin = new google.maps.Point(10, 50);
      loc.title = "Parkrun: " + loc.parkrun + ", Runner: " + loc.name + ", Time: " + loc.duration;
      loc.label = {
        text: loc.name + ", Time:" + loc.duration,
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold',

      };
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker(loc);
      // Add listener for a click event upon which will open url for parkrun sites.
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        window.open(loc.link);
      });
    });
}

jsonData = [{
  "position": {
    "lat": 51.1699,
    "lng": -0.8371
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Alice Holt",
  "name": "James Baker",
  "duration": "16:57:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/aliceholt\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 51.2193,
    "lng": -1.5052
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Andover",
  "name": "John Kane",
  "duration": "18:13:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/andover\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 51.2599,
    "lng": -1.0824
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Basingstoke",
  "name": "Matthieu Marshall",
  "duration": "16:51:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/basingstoke\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 50.8084,
    "lng": -1.6414
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Brockenhurst",
  "name": "James Bewley",
  "duration": "18:06:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/brockenhurst\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 50.9705,
    "lng": -1.3731
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Eastleigh",
  "name": "Tom Bray",
  "duration": "18:06:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/eastleigh\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 50.8483,
    "lng": -1.166
  },
  "gender": "Women",
  "parkrun": "Fareham",
  "name": "Leslie Ellul",
  "duration": "52:00:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/fareham\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 50.8733,
    "lng": -0.9753
  },
  "gender": "Women",
  "parkrun": "Havant",
  "name": "Nicola Ellul",
  "duration": "26:10:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/havant\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 51.1188,
    "lng": -0.8766
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Hogmoor Inclosure",
  "name": "James Kingston",
  "duration": "17:07:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/hogmoorinclosure\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 50.8009,
    "lng": -1.2035
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Lee-on-the-Solent",
  "name": "Jack Porter",
  "duration": "18:24:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/leeonthesolent\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 50.7506,
    "lng": -1.547
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Lyminghton Woodside",
  "name": "Callum Johnson",
  "duration": "18:39:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/lymingtonwoodside\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 50.8685,
    "lng": -1.3427
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Netley Abbey",
  "name": "Samuel Skinner",
  "duration": "18:24:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/netleyabbey\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 50.8405,
    "lng": -1.0776
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Portsmouth Lakeside",
  "name": "Liam Dunne",
  "duration": "16:18:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/portsmouthlakeside\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 50.9651,
    "lng": -0.9754
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Queen Elizabeth",
  "name": "Grant Hopkins",
  "duration": "19:33:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/queenelizabeth\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 51.265,
    "lng": -0.7547
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Rushmoor",
  "name": "Kim Bowling",
  "duration": "17:18:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/rushmoor\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 50.9245,
    "lng": -1.4096
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Southampton",
  "name": "Peter Hart",
  "duration": "16:49:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/southampton\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 50.7787,
    "lng": -1.082
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Southsea",
  "name": "Adam Barlow",
  "duration": "16:31:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/southsea\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 50.8847,
    "lng": -1.2472
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Whiteley",
  "name": "Richard Waldron",
  "duration": "15:46:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/whiteley\/",
  "icon": []
}, {
  "position": {
    "lat": 51.0662,
    "lng": -1.3126
  },
  "gender": "Male",
  "parkrun": "Winchester",
  "name": "Marley Godden",
  "duration": "17:59:00",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.parkrun.org.uk\/winchester\/",
  "icon": []
}];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly now I don't know what was wrong with me